# Delete images from media library when user deletes an image from ACF Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gallery

When a user deletes an image from the gallery in wp-admin I need it to be deleted from the media library too. I have a function using the acf/update_value hook which works uncorrectly. When a user simply updates a post, WordPress removes all images from the media library and current gallery field. Please tell me how to fix it? All the old questions don't work :(

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/type=gallery', 'remove_gallery_images', 10, 3);

function remove_gallery_images($value, $post_id, $field) {
    $images_to_delete = array();
    $old_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['name'], true);
    $old_value = maybe_unserialize($old_value);
    if (!is_array($old_value)) {
        return $value;
    }
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $images_to_delete = $old_value;
    } else {
        foreach ($old_value as $image_id) {
            if (!in_array($image_id, $value)) {
                $images_to_delete[] = $image_id;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count($images_to_delete)) {
        foreach ($images_to_delete as $image_id) {
            wp_delete_attachment($image_id, true);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Is `$value` actually a plain array containing nothing but image IDs?

Comment: _"When a user deletes an image from the gallery in wp-admin I need it to be deleted from the media library too"_ - I hope you have _ensured_ that the same image can not be contained in more than one such gallery field to begin with then? Otherwise, you might be deleting images from the library that are still in use elsewhere.